# Cannot read property 'NativeProps' of undefined

Tags: react-native

I am using Rn v0.46.1 and it was working fine until yesterday.

I am on Android.

Now, I am getting these errors:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What was you last task? Maybe another `yarn install` to a new dependency? It could have been also upgraded your react-version to alpha13 which makes more trouble than being usefull.

**Some suggestions:**

change the entry for react-native in your package.json to "0.46.1" away from "^0.46.1" and also the react-version to "16.0.0.-alpha12" away from "^16.0.0.0-alpha-somewhat". The detail of this change is to remove any caret and any tilde in the version-number!

The react-16-alpha version changed with alpha13 into a horrible creature that makes a lot of NON-fun for react native. I've also lost some time with it.

After you've moved away from the caret/tilde to concrete version numbers you should do "yarn install" again and see if you can build. If your issue still persists, remove the node_modules folder completely and reinstall with "yarn install".

If it also won't help, try to create a new rn-project and place your dependencies there to see if you can create a pure example-application that can document these issues.

Another final solution would be to downgrade to 0.45.1

Comment: tnx for suggestions but In my `package.json` its already  ` "react": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
    "react-native": "0.46.1",`

Comment: and yes I tried to install react-native-navigation but that didnt worked out so I removed it

Comment: ok. whats about remove node_modules completely and reinstall?

Comment: I didnt wanted to do that but I think I have no option . Sure will tell you after doing that

Comment: you might make a copy of it before if you are afraid that nothing will work again :)

Comment: nope, that didnt solved the issue , now getting `undefined is not a object (evaluating 'UIManager.RCTView.NativeProps')`

Comment: with react@16.0.0-alpha13 the NativeProps was removed. Which version dou you find in node_modules/react/package.json?

Comment: `"react": "16.0.0-alpha.12",`

Comment: now getting new series of errors: `Cannot read property 'connect' of undefined`, `Requiring module "InitializeCore", which threw an exception: TypeError: Cannot read property 'connect' of undefined`

Comment: `AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication)`

Comment: seams that your redux isnt installed well.

all in all, the last one with Appregistry this is a follow-up-error if initialize-process failed.

Comment: with disabled debug, getting this : `undefined is not an object (evaluating 'RCTWebSocketModule.connect') WebSocket`

Comment: i would suggest once more to build a new application from scratch, add your libararies. If you can build, then copy over your own code files. Sounds strange, but this was mostly the only way to fix those issues. This is react-native, right. Based on a alpha-version of React, that will break everything when it came from alpha3 to alpha6 and again from alpha12 to alpha13 and so on .....

Comment: ya , did the same and it worked and yes I found it strange !